# In R, how do you create a function that evaluates arguments as strings?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, grepl

I have a large dataset and am trying to search through it for keywords. Doing this interactively, I've been using `grep` alike so:

```
fee <- grep("fi", fo$fum)
View(fi$fum[fee, ])
```

This works well enough for my purposes but it has a lot of repetitive typing. I figured I would speed up the process a little by writing a function:

```
giant_search <- function(x, y) {
    y <- grep(quote(x), fo$fum)
    return(y)
    View(fo$fum[y, ])
}
```

When I use this function, however, y returns no values (so, of course, View doesn't show anything either).  However if I write the exact same code outside of the function it works exactly as I want/expect it to.

I assume the issue is with how R deals with function arguments or strings within a function, but I cannot figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: No need for `quote(x)` as `grep` takes a string argument. Anything after `return` will be ignored so move `return` to the end of your function. Finally, if you will use `y` just inside the function then no need to passe it as an argument.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the `giant_search()` function? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: MrFlick, I was calling it as `giant_search(giant_name)`.  Running A. Suliman's solution below, I realize that part of my problem was that the arguments weren't being passed into the function as strings (i.e. I should have done `giant_search(x='giant_name')` instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
giant_search <- function(x, y){
y <- grep(x, iris$Species)
View(iris[y, ])
return(y)
}
giant_search(x='setosa')
```